# Linux server phpmyadmin , I cannot login anymore configuration error 2002 . Config.inc empty?

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin on linux server, worked fine for a couple of weeks, but now suddenly I cannot login to phpMyAdmin anymore. I can connect from my website, but cannot login manually on the server.

I have googled and searched on this forum but alle the suggestions include editing the file /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Strange thing is, this file is empty. Nothing in it. So I guess, that could be my problem, but then why is it now empty and not before? And is there a default I can restore or is this something generated upon installation?

The real question I am asking myself now is, am I hacked? If not, why would this file be empty?

EDIT: directly trying to connect via SSH gives an error too: Can`t connect to local mysql server throught socket '/var/run..'

EDIT2: I did a search for files named config.inc.php and found one in /etc/phpmyadmin, this one has a lot of settings so I guess I was looking into the wrong file.. Everything from Authentication Type is not active 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the status of your mysql server? On Debian based systems you can run sudo service mysql status. Most Redhat based it is /etc/init.d/mysql status.

Comment: It says stopped, and if I restart, it says failed. However I am still possible to run websites on this DB server.. PS: I did found a config.inc file in a differten location now, with settings.

Comment: Do you have an error message when it fails? If not try looking at /var/log/mysql.err. So this now goes past programming and into sysadmin. If you site uses the database then it will fail. If not then it may still be running.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It does not give an error. I did get this error trying to connect to mysql via ssh: "Can`t connect to local mysql server throught socket '/var/run..'" Also, the website are querying database, I can add a page in the backend of a wordpress site, using this server as databaseserver. Strange right?

Comment: The log is completely empty btw.

Comment: Try ps -ax | grep mysql.

Comment: Returns 2 recors. Record 1: 1444 ?        Ssl   52:59 /usr/sbin/mysqld
Record 2: 11444 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

Comment: Sounds like it is stuck trying to stop, and therefore failing on restarting.

Comment: Somehow, i can run sudo service mysql restart succesfull, service mysql status returns running proces. But when I execute /etc/init.d/mysql/restart, it fails.

Comment: Maybe system reboot will help then?

Comment: Oke, this is crazy. I rebooted the system and now it is working fine again. Any idea on what may have caused this?

Comment: Not really. It is hard to say without more information. It could be several things. But if I were you I'd begin pouring over logs. Mysql logs. Web server logs. Just to be sure that a breach has not occurred or that you have a more serious issue.That's what I'd do anyway.